# Reading XML nested node values

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Having an issue grabbing values in an XML file
The structure is as followed

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
       <add key="folder" value = "c:\...." />
    </settings>
</configuration>
```

i want to be able to read the value from folder.

```
string val = string.Empty;

        foreach (XElement element in XElement.Load(file).Elements("configuration"))
        {
            foreach (XElement element2 in element.Elements("settings"))
            {
                if (element2.Name.Equals("folder"))
                {
                    val = element2.Attribute(key).Value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return val;
```

Comment: that's not the app.config file for your application is it?

Comment: it's from another application I need to read for values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the *element* isn't `folder`... that's the value of the `key` attribute. Also note that as you've used `XElement.Load`, the element *is* the `configuration` element - asking for `Elements("configuration")` will give you an empty collection. You could either load an `XDocument` instead, or just assume you're on a `configuration` element and look beneath it for `settings`.

I think you want:

```
return XElement.Load(file)
               .Elements("settings")
               .Elements("add")
               .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("key") == "folder")
               .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("value"))
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath:

```
var folder = XElement.Load(file)
                     .XPathSelectElements("/settings/add[@key='folder']")
                     .Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("value"))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: much better than the chosen answer!